# I encounter this issue while scaling object, how can I fix it?

Tags: modeling, scale

Whenever I scale my object in edit mode, I receive what I want after I scale it but the object got deform if I actually look from any other angles. Here is the picture of the view after I scaled the object:
[image]

And here what it actually looks like:
[image]

It supposes to look like a bigger bowl but instead looks like a flat piece of paper

Comment: Have you changed your transform pivot point at all?

Comment: maybe you have enabled the snapping option and it sticks to a plane? (magnet icon button on the top header)

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I am new to Blender. Would you mind explaining what "transform pivot" means?

Comment: @moonboots Thanks a lot :))

Comment: If you look at the top-middle of your 3D viewport, right between the coordinate picker (where it says "Global") and the icon that looks like a magnet (snapping), there is an icon with what looks like 2 interlinked rings. This is the transform pivot selection menu. From here, you can pick the "transform pivot" you want. For example, the default is "median point", so if you select 2 faces anywhere on your mesh, and attempt to scale them, they will scale relative to eachother (either together or apart.)  But, if you select "Active element", they will scale relative to the last face selected.